# Trying to calculate the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the DateDiff function is off

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I am trying to calculate the number of days that have passed between 1/1/1900 and 5/1/2019.

I have tried this using several dates and get the same out come.
The value returned is 2 days off.

```
--
-- calculate the number of days between 1/1/1900 and 5/1/2018
--
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(DATE,'1/1/1900'),CONVERT(DATE,'5/1/2018'))
```

Expected Result: 43221
  Actual Result: 43219

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just curious: how do you know it's 43221?

Comment: 43219 looks right to me. Are you suffering from Excelitis, perhaps? Excel has some incorrect ideas about which years are leap years.

Comment: Excel and SQL Server don't have the same value for the date `0`. if you're comparing the 2, they are not the same.

Comment: For example in SQL Server 05 Jan 2018 is 43103, and in Excel it's 43105 (which is neither of the values you have).

Comment: https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/day-counter?c=EUR&v=a:-25567,b:17652 also tells me that 43219 is correct

Comment: Java with LocalDate also gives result: 43219

Comment: Think you're right @JeroenMostert , if 5/1/2018 is 01 May 2018 (rather than 05 Jan 2018) then you get 43221 in Excel, but 43219 in SQL Server. Of course, we all know that Excel is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATEDIFF returns the number of days *between* the two dates. So if you want 1900-01-01 to be numbered as day 1, then you must add 1 to any difference you get from DATEDIFF. In Excel, day 0 is 1899-12-31.

Secondly, Excel treats 1900 as a leap year, and has a 29-Feb-1900 (day 60 in the Excel numbering system iirc). This was a holdover from Lotus 1-2-3 which originally used a simplified algorithm for leap years (treating every year divisible by 4 as a leap), and remains for backward compatibility

If you combine these two faults, these account for your off-by-two results.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply's I appreciate it.
I'm working with an on-line application that passes date information entered in a form via URL. The date range I entered was:
5/1/2018 - 5/1/2019

The values passed in the URL were:
43221 - 43586

I used this as the basis of my assumption that the DateDiff function was giving me the wrong result.  Now that I think about it there could be some magic in the background of the App I'm unaware of that's being used to generate the values...I'm not sure.

anyways...thanks!